# Why set a drawable shape in layout background will be warn?

Tags: android, android-studio, background, warnings, shapedrawable

Why setting a layout background with shape drawable causes a warning on Android Studio 1.4 telling that cannot set background in `RelativeLayout`?

Android Studio warning about invalid background:

[image]

Drawable `shape` used as background:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to be concerned about. It is an android studio problem, it normally shows a preview icon of the drawable, but in this case it cannot show a preview of a drawable XML and shows that "error"

Comment: good, why FrameLayout cannot set background, do not show the suggestions!

Comment: Not sure if Android Studio dev team will have a look on this, but I have opened a ticket for investigation: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196394

Comment: According someone from the Android Studio project, this issue is reproducible on `Android Studio v1.5.0` & `Android Studio v1.5.1`, but not on `Android Studio 2.0 Preview 2`